# How to loop rigid body simulation blender

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, loop, looping

[image]

[image]

These balls I have simulated using Rigid Body. So I need to create this simulation as a loop. The first frame and the last frame should be created in the same way. I tried to do it several times. But it is not successful. Can you tell me a way to do it?

Comment: i think you have to do this manually (maybe someone comes up with a genius idea) but since the balls are falling randomly, i think you have to manually keyframe them to the start frame positions....

Comment: Ok friend. I will try. Thank you!

Comment: For RB sim you can just a trick it by illusion - animate mix-stop-mix and crop animation by let it start from middle of the first mix and end at middle of second mix. There would be the biggest chance to trick your eye it is continuing animation (balls are at that point fast and randomly scattered, just take care the "blades" rotation to match start-end keyframe).

Comment: yes it would be easier to fix in the video sequencer